# Unable to run Selenium RC server as windows service

Tags: windows-services, selenium-rc

I have followed this link to run Selenium Server as a windows service: http://www.claytonstechnobabble.com/2011/08/run-any-application-as-windows-service.html

The service gets installed successfully but when I try to run it it gives error:

"The SeleniumRC service on Local Computer started and then stopped. Some services stop automatically if they are not in use by other services or programs."

can you guys help me on that asap? what am I missing?

This is the selenium server file that I am trying to run: "selenium-server-standalone-2.5.0.jar"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running Selenium RC as a Windows Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4164090/running-selenium-rc-as-a-windows-service)

Answer (score 0):

Ali, you might try capturing the output from the service.  Since the Java app is designed to be run in console mode, there is likely to be some useful explanation if you can capture std out and std err.  Running the service with a wrapper like Java Service Launcher will provide that functionality to log the error information: http://jslwin.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Yeah, we use JSL to run Selenium RC as a service on Windows Server 2003, and it works great.  @Ali: You can add the `-log ...location...` option to force the server to create a log file.

Answer (score 0):

Create a bat file containing

```
//cd Location of file    
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.5.0.jar
```

then use this bat file to execute in service.