# Running Selenium Server standalone 2 as a service in windows XP

Tags: windows, service, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How can I run Selenium Server Standalone 2 as a windows service in Windows XP?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running Selenium RC as a Windows Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4164090/running-selenium-rc-as-a-windows-service)

Answer (score 4):

Or if you want it start at startup, you can do this:

1. Create file `01_start_hub.bat` which will contain this command:

   ```
   java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.20.0.jar -role hub
   ```
2. Create file `02_start_node.bat` which will contain this command:

   ```
   java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.20.0.jar -role node  -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register
   ```
3. Place both bat files into Startup folder `C:\Documents and Settings\UserName\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`

Yes you will have two "ugly" dos prompts after startup, but this is quickwin solutin

Answer (score 2):

http://brantleytec.blogspot.com/2012/11/selenium-hub-and-node-as-windows-service.html

That link describes the process I used to set up and use Selenium hub and node as a service using native Microsoft programs. I was able to get this running locally on my work PC as well as on a remote server which runs my tests after every build.

If this is for your local PC though, I might suggest using the ChromeDriver instead of the RemoteWebDriver.  It's less setup and allows new hires to start using your tests without any extra setup.

Comment: Does this still work with recent versions of Chrome? From various other reports, it seems that since version 38, Chrome+Selenium+ChromeDriver will not work when installed as a service (apparently because the Session 0 used by windows services is headless, and this is not officially supported)

Answer (score 1):

I've had a lot of luck with the [Non-Sucking Service Manager](http://nssm.cc/). It's a standalone executable that creates and a windows service and works much better than any alternatives I've ever used (I'm thinking about srvany.exe). The [usage instructions](http://nssm.cc/usage) are pretty straightforward.

Here's how I used it:

1. Download and extract nssm.exe
2. I wanted to run a single instance that acted as both the hub and a node, so I didn't specify a role. I also just wanted the default settings, so I didn't pass in any parameters. Here's what I did from the command line: *nssm install Selenium-Server "C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\java.exe" "-jar C:\Selenium\selenium-server-standalone-2.21.0.jar"*

If you want to run as just a hub or a node, then add in the -role hub or -role node to the last parameter in step #2, e.g. "-jar C:\Selenium\selenium-server-standalone-2.21.0.jar -role hub". You can specify any other parameters for Selenium here as well.

If you need to adjust the parameters later, you can do this through Regedit under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\\Parameters. Specifically, the AppParameters Key contains the parameters you pass to Selenium.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the following project...
I've used it to setup my Minecraft Server (java project) as a windows service.

http://yajsw.sourceforge.net/

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

And here is link to more durable solution - first create the BAT files as in my other answer. Second [read this article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/251192) - Its about creating the service. I would reccomend pointing out to the BAT files in the options.

I never created a service, so that help page is as much as I can offer